# Angular unknown element

Tags: angular

```
<li class="nav-item ml-0 ml-md-auto" ngbDropdown #dropdown="ngbDropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle>
          <i class="fa fa-user mr-1"></i>
          <span *ngIf="!token">Accounts</span>
        </a>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
          <a *ngIf="token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/profile" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profile
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="!token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/login" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();logout();" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout
          </a>
          <a *ngIf="!token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/register" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-group" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

the first line of code ----#dropdown="ngbDropdown"---- I did some research and still don't have a clue on what this means. i don't know what it's called so having trouble looking it up on documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngbDropdown` is a Directive added by the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) Package.

The `#dropdown="ngbDropdown"` is standard Angular Code making the Directive accessible by the variable `dropdown` (it is called [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars)). The variable is used by the `(click)="closeDropdown(dropdown)` actions.